# Why I recieve invalid csrf token?

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, spring-cloud-security

I have a project with spring-cloud-security. It's a auth server for oauth authorization. It's worked fine in the past.

I add spring profile for ssl support with cofiguration:

```
security:
  require-ssl: true
server:
  ssl:
    key-store: dev.p12
    key-store-password: devpass
    keyStoreType: PKCS12
    keyAlias: calc
```

With this profile, authentication works fine, but when I disable it and go to login via http, authentication breaks down.

```
o.s.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter         : Invalid CSRF token found for http://localhost:8090/login
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 26):

Your server has [CSRF](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CSRF) enabled. The `@EnableWebSecurity` annotation will enable CSRF by default as stated in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.x/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-configure).

> CSRF protection is enabled by default with Java configuration.

There are two ways to "fix" this, either disable CSRF or [submit the CSRF-token](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.x/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-include-csrf-token) when doing `PATCH`, `POST`, `PUT`, and `DELETE` actions.

To disable CSRF do it in the Spring Security configuration

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
  }
}
```

To submit the CSRF-token you must include it in the request to the server (in this example a JSP with sending a `POST` request)

```
<c:url var="logoutUrl" value="/logout"/>
<form action="${logoutUrl}" method="post">
  <input type="submit" value="Log out" />
  <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
    value="${_csrf.token}"/>
</form>
```

All examples taken from the Spring [Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF) documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.x/reference/html/csrf.html)

Please consider the recommendation from Spring when considering whether to disable CSRF

> [...] use CSRF protection for any request that could be processed by a
> browser by normal users. If you are only creating a service that is
> used by non-browser clients, you will likely want to disable CSRF
> protection.

Comment: Csrf worked fine before ssl. After this, I have error, when I use it with http protocol. Maybe something cashed in browser?

Comment: In Spring 6.x you can do : `http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);`